# Get new mails notification from GMail?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, gmail, notifications

Is there an easy way to get a notification from Google when a Google Mail user gets a new mail? Read- /write support, etc. is not needed.

I'm looking for solutions in C, Objective-C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can either access the account via IMAP (has to be enabled in the users GMail settings) or wait for [their official tool](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) to support GMail.